# What is the point of PvM in UO?

Tags: ultima-online

I played UO several years ago with some friends and it was fun and everything, but it seemed like there was literally almost nothing to do except PvP.  However I was pretty twinked out, I supposed, maybe this is why PvM didn't seem that useful?  Still, I played a considerable amount and found almost no drops of any value and certainly no interesting loot at all.  I think the best thing I found was like gems and reagents from farming dragons.

Is there anything else to it or is that basically it?  (Vanilla UO, not talking about special custom server encounters or anything)

Comment: I assume UO meant "Ultima Online", but if it didn't, please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, I've not played Ultima Online in some time, so maybe my answer is a bit out of date.
Having said that however I wish to provide some input.

Some items can only be acquired trough PvM, such as [powerscrolls](http://www.uoguide.com/Power_Scrolls)<sup>1</sup>, [statscrolls](http://www.uoguide.com/Stat_Scrolls) and the [gauntlet artifacts](http://www.uoguide.com/Artifacts_(Doom)#The_Gauntlet). I'd argue that powerscrolls might be the most interesting reason to PvM as they are generally sought after and 120-scrolls are rare and expensive. Either you could hunt them for a chance to get a "cheap" 120-scroll or to make gold by selling the scrolls you obtain. This makes it meaningful for someone to go into PvM, much for the same reasons someone would go into crafting (better items or gold). Neither of these might be a reason for you to go into PvM, but PvM:ing is obviously a meaningful part of the game.

PvM is also useful when starting out, as you gain skill, gold and starter equipment.

<sup>1</sup>Crafting powerscrolls are obtainted by filling out [Bulk Order Deeds](http://www.uoguide.com/Bulk_Order_Deed).